# PHP IMAP mail decode subject - mb_decode_mimeheader - destroy EUR symbol

Tags: php, email, decode, symbols, corrupt

We are sucessfully reading IMAP mail for some following business logic. Now we have noticed that when decrypting the email subject, the EUR symbol is corrupt. To fetch all mails and decode the subject we are using something like this:

```
$imapInstance; // already given and initialiced;
$mails = imap_fetch_overview($imapInstance, 0 . ':' 2); // for example

foreach ($mails as $mail) {
    $mail->subject = mb_decode_mimeheader($mail->subject)
}
```

- Subject in Mail = `TestTest€, öäüÖÄÜ@ß'"&&/()=?!"§$%²³|;TestTest`
- Subject before decode = `=?utf-8?B?VGVzdFRlc3TigqwsIMO2w6TDvMOWw4TDnEDDnyciJiYvKCk9PyEiwqckJcKy?= =?utf-8?B?wrN8O1Rlc3RUZXN0?=`
- Subject after decode = `TestTest¤, öäüÖÄÜ@ß'"&&/()=?!"§$%²³|;TestTest`

After some research, I also tried '`iconv_mime_decode`' & '`imap_utf8`'. In both cases, the result was the same. Does anyone have a tip for me about what could be going wrong? The emails were sent with Outlook.

Comment: Works fine here, https://3v4l.org/4bc5I Are you sure that you are _interpreting_ the result as UTF-8?

Comment: Maybe that Outlook converts the  `€` (U+20AC,  *Euro Sign*) to `¤` (U+00A4,  *Currency Sign*) considering, in their eternal wisdom, every _money_ the same?

Comment: Really strange. I have already somehow the suspicion that it arrives already broken. I'll check it out on Monday. It's probably really due to Outlook. Considering the fact that all other characters are decoded correctly, I assume that the mentioned UTF-8 encoding is already correct.